# MarkLogic Additional French Characters Issue

Tags: marklogic

We are facing some issues in marklogic with french characters we have a word with french characters like "«fœtus»", when we do a xdmp:save or log of this word there are additional french characters being appended to it like "Â«fœtusÂ»". Is this a encoding issue or is there a setting that need to be enabled for it to not happen. Please help.

Comment: Can you post some code that we could use to try to reproduce what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

That definitely looks like an encoding issue, most likely Latin-1 being processed as UTF-8 or vice versa. See [Encoding debugging table](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html)  How to fix it rather depends on where the problem is coming: on the load side, you should add the encoding option; on the display side, you need to tell your browser what the actual encoding is. If you want to force a particular encoding on output you can set that in the prolog options of your query or at the appserver level.